# Difference between WMS layers and XYZ-Tiles

Tags: qgis

When I want to download a basemap that represents my study area, I can use WMS Services or I load a XYZ Tile from lets say OSM.

But where is the difference? Perhaps it's that XYZ-Tiles are always basemaps whereas WMS Services might be Images of texts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An XYZ tile service provides tiles based on a URL template with values substituted in for Zoom Level and X and Y counts of the tile. They are (usually) limited to a fixed projection (usually EPSG:3857).

A WMS provides an image of the map using a set of key value pairs (KVP) to specify which layers, styles, projection and size to use. It is possible to request tiles in this way too as the WMS protocol is stateless.

A WMTS layer provides predefined tiles (like an XYZ service) with an option to use a RESTful templated URL or a KVP request and with a variety of projections and grids.

Answer (score -1):

TMS - images generated ones time stored in directories with Z-level 
WMS - images generated "on the fly" from data base in vector format.